# Xiaomi Mi A1 System Update installation problem

Tags: updates, xiaomi, mi-a1

I wanna update my mi A1 phone through System update. It download the file but I get "Installation Problem" Error.

Is there any way to solve the problem? Or any way to download the file and install it manually? I downloaded it 3 times and every time got the same error.

[image: screenshot] [image: screenshot]
<sup>Screenshots (click to enlarge)</sup>

Comment: Same problem here =( Did u install Gcam?

Comment: No I didn't.
This [this is what i did](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/196131/xiaomi-mi-a1-phone-wont-turn-on?noredirect=1#comment252349_196131) and now I can't turn the phone on :,(