# Xiaomi Mi A1 phone won't turn on

Tags: xiaomi, 8.1-oreo, mi-a1

I tried to install android 8.1 on my Mi A1 phone by following instructions from [this site](http://www.stechguide.com/install-android-8-1-oreo-beta-on-xiaomi-mi-a1/#comment-13184). After finishing the installation when I tried to reboot the phone, The phone turned off and I cant turn it on again.

When I hold the power button or when I connect the phone to PC, the LED start blinking with a vibration.

Please help... I bought the phone recently and I think I destroyed it in less than a weak :'‑(

Comment: Have you rooted your device? May be a solution can be found from here : https://forum.xda-developers.com/mi-a1

Comment: @RahulGopi no it is not rooted.